# Change name of column after uniqueN function

Tags: r, data.table

I am already happy with the results, but want to further tidy up my data by giving the right name to the respective column.
The problem to solve is to give the number of different authors which are included for each years publication between 2000 and 2010. Here is my code and my result:

```
books_dt[Year_Of_Publication <= 2010 & Year_Of_Publication >= 2000, uniqueN(Book_Author), by = "Year_Of_Publication"][order(Year_Of_Publication)]

  Year_Of_Publication    V1
1:                2000 12057
2:                2001 11818
3:                2002 11942
4:                2003  9913
5:                2004  4536
6:                2005    38
7:                2006     3
8:                2008     1
9:                2010     2
```

The numbers in the result are right, but I want to change the column name V1 to something like "Num_Of_Dif_Auth". I tried the `setnames` function, but as I don`t want to change the underlying dataset it didn´t help.

Comment: see `?colnames()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(data.table)

books_dt[Year_Of_Publication <= 2010 & Year_Of_Publication >= 2000, 
        .(Num_Of_Dif_Auth = uniqueN(Book_Author)), 
         by = Year_Of_Publication][order(Year_Of_Publication)]
```